# Swift with XCode 6 Beta 7 has troubles with register notifications

Tags: xcode, swift, notifications, ios8, xcode6

I am developing an application with Swift and XCode 6. Yesterday I installed XCode 6 beta 7 and a part of my code (which was already running before this install) now crashing with bad access error.

Here is the part of my code:

```
    var types: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

The crashing line is `let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)`. The error is: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x20)`

Does anybody has an idea about this?

Comment: Did you migrate from beta6?

Comment: What kind of migration that you mean? I just copied IOS 7.1 SDK to new beta to support 7.1

Comment: `which was already running before this install` on witch xCode version did you run the code?

Comment: It was XCode 6 Beta 6.. Just upgraded to Beta 7

Comment: Did you clean your working directory? This should always be done when a new beta comes out.

Comment: Yes I did... But unfortunately nothing in return...

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting 7.1 (or anything < 8.0)? The API you're using is 8.0 only. From the Apple docs:

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
func registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)

@availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
class UIUserNotificationSettings : NSObject {
  ...
}
```